# How to record two tracks of audio while recording video?

Tags: audio, video

I am trying to make some instructional videos of myself playing guitar and I'm using my Galaxy S7 as my video recorder. For the audio, I have two microphones going into a Behringer mixer and want to take the stereo outputs (Main Out) from that and feed them into my phone's headphone jack. Can someone tell me what cables/adapters I should be using? I don't fully understand the TRRS jack on the Android and how I can interface it with the two tip/sleeve cables coming out of the mixer. Is there a cable that will take a stereo output from one device and connect it to the TRRS input on an Android, enabling both audio tracks to be recorded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a cable that will take a stereo output from one device and connect it to the TRRS input on an Android, enabling both audio tracks to be recorded?

No. The TRRS headset jack isn't for connecting a stero *input*. It's for connecting a mono input (the mic) and a stereo output (the headphones), along with some extra cleverness for inline volume and transport buttons.

I don't think the OS itself supports two audio tracks as input, but if it does, the only way will be with one of those mini-mixers that connects via USB, and a USB-On-the-Go adapter. Be sure to check with the vendor that the mixer supports Android before you buy.